# Cauchy's problem. Equation of mathematical physics

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

> $$U_{tt} = \Delta U + x^3 - 3xy^2$$
>
> $$U|_{t=0} = e^x \cos y$$
>
> $$U_t|_{t=0} = e^y \sin x$$

Help me, please, with solution of this equation. Can you prompt me algorithm to find the solution? I know, that I have to use Poisson's formula, but I can't integrate it.

Comment: I think it would be better if you explicitly write up the integral that you need to solve. That way, you both show some effort, and you spare respondents some work. There may be many people here that are good at integrating but not so familiar with PDEs, and this would allow them to help.

Comment: Specify which type of solution is need. If you wish a numerical solution apply finite difference method. If it is a one dimensional web equation and if you wish an analytic solution apply D' Alembert's method. For higher dimensional web equation there is solution but difficult to find. Please specify your choice.

Comment: >$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^t\int_0^{t-\tau}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r\cos(\phi)+x)^3 - 3(r\cos(\phi)+x)(r\sin(\phi)+y)^2}{\sqrt{(t-\tau)^2 - r^2}}r d\phi dr d\tau + $$
>$$ +\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^t\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(e^{r\sin(\phi)+y}\sin(r\cos(\phi)+x)}{\sqrt{t^2 - r^2 }}r d\phi dr +$$
>$$+ \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^t\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(e^{r\cos(\phi)+x}\cos(r\sin(\phi)+y)}{\sqrt{t^2 - r^2 }}r d\phi dr$$

It's received integral. How it integrated? Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that the solution of this problem
\begin{align*}
&\text{PDE:}~~u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}+x^3-3xy^2, \qquad (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, t>0,\\
&\text{IC:}~~ u(x,y,0)=\operatorname{e}^x\cos(y),\quad u_t(x,y,0)=\operatorname{e}^y\sin(x),\qquad (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2
\end{align*}
is 
\begin{gather*}
u(x,y,t)=\operatorname{e}^x\cos(y)+t\cdot \operatorname{e}^y\sin(x)+\frac{t^2}{2}\cdot \big(x^3-3xy^2\big).
\end{gather*}
Although you can evaluate this solution by using directly the Poisson's formula, it is very tricky, and easy, to break it into three simple problems, for the given problem is linear, and then all the things are simple.

Indeed, let 
\begin{gather*}
u(x,y,t)=v(x,y,t)+w(x,y,t)+q(x,y,t),
\end{gather*}
where $v$ solves
\begin{align*}
&v_{tt}(x,y,t)=v_{xx}(x,y,t)+v_{yy}(x,y,t),\\
&v(x,y,0)=\operatorname{e}^x\cos(y), \quad v_t(x,y,0)=0,
\end{align*}
and $w$ solves
\begin{align*}
&w_{tt}(x,y,t)=w_{xx}(x,y,t)+w_{yy}(x,y,t),\\
&w(x,y,0)=0, \quad v_t(x,y,0)=\operatorname{e}^y\sin(x),
\end{align*}
and as well $q$ solves
\begin{align*}
&q_{tt}(x,y,t)=q_{xx}(x,y,t)+x^3-3xy^2,\\
&q(x,y,0)=0, \quad q_t(x,y,0)=0.
\end{align*}
Observe that the three mappings 
\begin{gather*}
(x,y)\mapsto x^3-3xy^2,\\
(x,y)\mapsto \operatorname{e}^x\cos(y),\\
(x,y)\mapsto \operatorname{e}^y\sin(x)
\end{gather*}
are harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2,$ so it is promising to assume that 
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial v(x,y,t)}{\partial t}\equiv0,\\
w(x,y,t)=w^*(x,y)\cdot t,\\
q(x,y,t)=q^*(t)\cdot(x^3-3xy^2). 
\end{gather*}
Then to determine $w^*, q^*$ is trivial. Thus we would obtain that 
$v(x,y,t)=\operatorname{e}^x\cos(y), $ and $w(x,y,t)=\operatorname{e}^y\sin(x)\cdot t,$ and as well $q(x,y,t)=\frac{t^2}{2}\cdot (x^3-3xy^2).$